# Batch read each line from file

Tags: batch-file

I've this type of file txt:

```
007   87855
008   87823
015   87830
```

the two columns are divided by a tab

I want do this:

```
read each line of input.txt
if %%test == first_column_value_file
then assign %%second_column_value_file to %%var

"test" for example is 008.
```

when my %%a match with a value of the first column I can stop to read the file.
is it possible to do that in batch?

Answer (score 1):

It is too bad that the columns are separated by a tab. If they where separated with a space this would work...(directly from the commandline (so no batch file needed)

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= "  %a in (input.txt) do if %a==008 set result=%b
```

if you echo %result% you see the contect of the second token on the line that matches 008 as the first token.

This version can be used in a batch script and fixes the problem that the delimter is a tab (I have to learn to be not so precise/explicit).

```
set result=
for /f "tokens=1,2"  %%a in (input.txt) do if %%a==008 set result=%%b

echo Result is %result%
```

Comment: how can I obtain %b?what I mean, batch inserts first and second columns into %a and %b in automatic way?

Answer (score 1):

I used a mock version of @rene's answer to come up with this (not rene's answer will work as well)...

```
@echo off
set test=002
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (test.txt) do if %%a==%test% set var=%%b & goto end
:end
set test
set var
pause>nul
```

Contents of `test.txt`:

```
001 00001
002 00002
003 00003
```

Output of code:

```
test=002
var=00002
```

Comment: That sentence was supposed to be `note rene's answer will work as well`.

Comment: In my commandline variant I also did the & goto :eof to break-out of the for early. That only works in a command script though. +1

Comment: @rene Did it answer your question, or just help you? If it didn't answer it, how can I make it better?

Comment: I'm not the one that asked the Question....I responded to your comments on my answer...yours is fine as well...

Comment: @rene I got your name and rschirin's mixed up. Maybe I scrolled down instead of up...

Comment: @ProfPickle why did you set test and var after :end? I don't understand that

Comment: @rschirin I didn't set a value to them. When you use `set variable` it displays the variable's value if it has one. So, `set test` (assuming the `test` variable is set) outputs `test=value`. Note, it's the same as writing `echo test=%test%`.

Comment: @ProfPickle I have another problem using your code. I wrote another question with number 15326594.